# In Perl, how to match several prefixes

Tags: regex, perl

I have 2 input files.  One is a list of prefix and lengths, like this:

```
101xxx
102xxx
30xx
31xx
```

(where x is any number)

And another is a list of numbers.

I want to iterate through the second file, matching each number against any of the prefix/lengths.  This is fairly easy.  I build a list of regexps:

```
my @regexps = ('101...', '102...', '30..', '31..');
```

Then:

```
foreach my $regexp (@regexps) {
    if (/$regexp/) {
        # do something
```

But, as you can guess, this is slow for a long list.

I could convert this to a single regexp:

```
my $super_regexp = '101...|102...|30..|31..';
```

...but, what I need is to know *which* regexp matched the item, and what the ..s matched.

I tried this:

```
my $catching_regexp = '(101)(...)|(102)(...)|(30)(..)|(31)(..)';
```

but then I don't know whether to look in $1, $3, %5 or $7.

Any ideas?  How can I match against any of these prefix/lengths and know which prefix, and what the remaining digits where?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a trie. It's easy to implement and it will be super-fast. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [branch reset pattern](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Alternative-capture-group-numbering), if your Perl is sufficiently recent (5.10 and newer):

```
my $regex = qr/^(?|(101)(...)|(102)(...)|(30)(..)|(31)(..))$/;
while (<>) {
    print "$1, $2\n" if /$regex/;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer OPs question, which is which (sub)expression matched.

Comment: @Qtax: In the given input, only one branch can match at any given time. Therefore, it's easy to find the matching one.

Comment: The input is an array of expressions. OP wants to know which expression matched. This doesn't answer that.

Comment: It does seem to answer - which prefix matched, and what the matching ... digits were.  Which is what I actually want to know.

Comment: @Qtax: The one that starts with $1 and continues with as many x'es as there are characters in $2 (`$1 . ('x' x length $2)`).

Comment: As a suggestion, you might compress that to `(?|(101|102)(...)|(30|31)(..))`

Comment: @Robin: Feel free to implement a regular automaton optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

I think I missed some of what you were going for.  If different prefixes have different sub-expressions (`...` vs `..`) and you want to capture/reference what the sub-expression matched...you can use a lookbehind:

```
((?<=101|102).{3}|(?<=30|31).{2})
```

This will capture everything, and if it is prefixed by `101|102` it will match 3 characters; if it is prefixed by `30|31`, it will match 2 characters.  We only use one capture group, so your `xxx`'s will always be in `$1`.

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/aL9wK3)

And if you also want to capture the prefix, you can [include a lazy capture group before the secondary grouping](http://regex101.com/r/iI0dN2) of lookbehinds:

```
(.*?)((?<=101|102).{3}|(?<=30|31).{2})
```

Your prefixes will be in group 1, and your suffixes in group 2.

---

Use alternation within a group:

```
(101|102|30|31)...
```

This will create an extra captured group, though..so you can also use a "non-capturing" group:

```
(?:101|102|30|31)...
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/qZ5yU0)

---

You can do as much logic as you want to with this mentality. It's similar to how you would need to group conditionals in any language:

```
if(a === true && (b === false || b === null)) {}
```

Comment: why not `(10[12]|3[01])`?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen yes this works, and actually would reduce the number of steps in many scenarios (so OP should use that method)..I was trying to purely answer the OP's question of alternation on a prefix.

Comment: `(10[12]|3[01])` looks like (premature) optimization.

Comment: This doesn't answer OPs question, which is which (sub)expression matched.

Comment: @Qtax it should be obvious $1 and $2.

Comment: Wouldn't this also match (for example) 30xxx? Which I don't want to match.

Comment: @mpapec, OP has several expressions, OPs question is which of the expressions matched. By putting them all in one group doesn't answer that question (without additional steps).

Comment: @Qtax it seems to me that OP is looking for matched values. Maybe I'm wrong.